# Components duplicating on front end

Tags: placeholders, dynamic-placeholder, webforms

We have a strange issue where components seem to be duplicating on the front end (web DB) but everything looks correct in the experience editor. I have checked the presentation details on both shared/final layouts in both master and web - but it looks fine. It also renders fine when viewing the experience editor when switching to web.

We are using dynamic placeholder - based on [this implementation](http://www.techphoria414.com/blog/2011/august/dynamic_placeholder_keys_prototype).

The strange thing is it was all working fine and then suddenly happened at some point but we can't track down what might be the cause.

Sitecore version: 8.2 - web forms.

Comment: It looks like an issue with Dynamics Placeholder. Could you try to put this component into the original placeholder (not into the dynamic)?

Comment: Do you use caching for any of the renderings?

Comment: @MarekMusielak yeah it was just down to caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just because caching had been mistakenly added to the Sublayouts that use dynamic placeholders.

*Edit (further explanation):*
We have a set of sublayouts/renderings that are used for page structure, and just contain (dynamic) placeholders - i.e. "one column row", "two column row" etc. They are just used to add actual components into. Adding caching to these sublayouts is a mistake because they could contain dynamic components within them and adding caching at this top level would cause these components to not function correctly.

In terms of why the caching caused duplication, I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about what scenario led to this issue and what things were changed to fix the issue.

Comment: Just to add onto what @DylanYoung suggested, can you elaborate on why caching on sublayouts that use dynamic placeholders is a bad thing? This will ensure that this content is helpful to other members as well, by educating them on why caching sublayouts with dynamic placeholders can cause issues.

Comment: @DylanYoung done